# How to run golang using docker?

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to use docker with go lang & PostgreSQL

I have this structure for the project:

```
-project_name
   - src
     - app
     - config
     - main.go
     - .env
     - docker-compose.yml 
     - Dockerfile
```

the docker-compose.yml file contains ( I need GO server & PostgreSQL)

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    container_name: logger_app
    build: ..
    ports:
      - "12000:12000"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - MYAPP

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DB_HOST}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - MYAPP

networks:
  MYAPP:
    driver: bridge
```

The Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM golang:1.18 as builder

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go get -d -v ./...

RUN go install -v ./...


RUN go build -o /build

EXPOSE 12000

CMD [ "/build" ]
```

when I run docker-compose up --build I got this error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount868285600/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the build line to `build: .` line. The compose file and Dockerfile are in the same directory.

Comment: I got another message `ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service app has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.
`

Comment: @kepemo2494 you probably want to define an image name, but for the build, it should have been `.` rather than `..`.

Comment: Thank you so much it works! I have a small question is my PostgresSQL environment correct like that? cuz I got this error when up docker `[error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to ``host=postgres_db user=root database=fresh`: failed SASL auth (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root" (SQLSTATE 28P01))``

Comment: See the Hub docs on how to use the postgres image: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres